# Why use job/step listeners instead of just two more steps/tasklets (one in the beginning and one the end)?

Tags: spring-batch

Since job listeners have callback methods that get executed before & after all the steps, can the same thing be achieved by having another step in the beginning of all steps and another step in the end? Or similarly instead of a step listener, have one tasklet before all tasklets and another tasklet at the end of all tasklets of a step? What is different about listeners that can't be done with two more steps or tasklets? Is it because listeners always get executed even in case of failures or is there some other design logic & need I fail to see?

Comment: Listeners and steps have different meanings, scope and transaction demarcation. Read carefully SB documentation and related examples and you will understand when and why use a step or a listener.

Comment: What can we do with listeners that we can't do with 2 steps/tasklets? And vice-versa?

Comment: Usually things can be done in different ways: you can have the same result using listeners or steps, but they have different scopes and utilities; probably you will reach your goal in short time frame, but problems and maintenance difficulties will come up in the middle-long time range.
But this question requires a complex answer and a SO question is not the right place for that.